# Is the water on Mars drinkable?

Tags: mars, water

Could water from Mars be fresh enough to drink? Could one run the water through a home water filter? I understand when water is frozen the salt is ejected as brine so would newly formed snow or ice be drinkable?

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16076/how-salty-can-snow-sleet-be

Comment: This has already been answered on the Space Exploration site at https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12135/is-water-on-mars-the-same-as-earth-water/12136#12136

Comment: From your previous questions and answers it seems pretty clear that it depends on the source of the water. Freezing can separate water from dissolved chemicals, but the resulting ice or snow can still be physically contaminated, so when you melt it, the resulting water will be contaminated. *Will home water filters desalinate?* That's not a question about astronomy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *Will home water filters desalinate?* is not a question about Astronomy.

Comment: @Muze this I believe is already answered.

Comment: Perchlorate salts are typically good solvable in water, and the Martial soil has a lot of them. They are also poisonous. Thus, probably also Martian water is poisonous without purification (mainly, multiple destillations).